# Parsing datetime string obtained from Django back-end in Java

Tags: java, django-rest-framework

I was wondering how could I parse a the following datetime string:

```
"2019-04-27T15:39:44.456276Z"
```

in Java?

the above date is coming from Django backed and I need to use it in android studio,
I tried many things with no success,
also I don't need smaller than minute resolution if that makes any difference
Please advice
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try with `java.time.Instant` (API level 26)

```
Instant t = Instant.parse("2019-04-27T15:39:44.456276Z");
```